# gave him the book to

Tags: infinitives, clauses

a. I told my theory to him to test it in the lab.

b. I shared my theory with him to test it in the lab.

The idea is that I wanted him to test it in the lab.

I told my theory to him/shared my theory with him so that he would test it in the lab,

Are sentences (a) and (b) grammatically correct and do they have the meaning I want them to have?

---

I don't think they do, but the following seem to work.

c. I gave him the book to give to Harry.

d. I gave the book to him to give to Harry.

e. I told him that story to tell the kids.

f. I told that story to him to tell the kids.

I think this 'structure' only works in certain cases.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rephrase a to "I told my theory to him so he could test it in the lab"

b is the same in that regard, same rephrasal. Current sentences sound awkward and maybe ambiguous.

c looks good.

d looks... alright, but I'd just say c.

I'd write "I told him that story so he could tell the kids" for e and f

Your sentences feel a bit ambiguous and awkward, but they are understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentences a and b don't have the meaning you want. They mean, "I told him my theory so ***I*** could test it in the lab", as if you needed his permission or something.

You then compare them with several other sentences (c to f) which have the function you're looking for. There's an important structural difference between your a and b sentences, and the c to f sentences:

a. "I told my theory to him to test ***it*** in the lab."

b. "I shared my theory with him to test ***it*** in the lab."

but

d. "I gave the book to him to give _____ to Harry." (no pronoun)

e. "I told him that story to tell _____ the kids." (no pronoun)

So, your sentences can have the function and meaning you want if you drop the pronoun after the infinitive. For example:

*b. I shared my theory with him to test in the lab.* (no "it")